# How to call a method whose parameter is a Class<Object> and Class<Map>

Tags: java, json, class, generics

I need to call a method , which is just used to deserialize a json string, the function is just like this:

```
 public <V extends Map<String,List<M>>,M> Object deserializeMap(String json, Class<Map> class1, Class<List> class2)
```

From its appearance,I know that it means this json string could be deserialized to a `Map` or a `List<Object>` and also , I know , this `Object` which represents each json item is a class named `MessageObj`,But how to construct these two parameters just confused me.Any one could help me?

Comment: Why can't you call it like `deserializeMap(urJsonString,Map.class,List.class)` ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the method signature and your explanation I guess that you should pass concrete classes which will be used to instantiate the resulting `Map` and `List`. In this case the method signature looks really strange. Note that generic arguments are not used at all. If you can change the method signature, probably it's better to define it like this:

```
public Object deserializeMap(String json, Class<? extends Map> class1, 
                             Class<? extends List> class2) {
    ...
}
```

And use like this:

```
deserializeMap(jsonString, HashMap.class, ArrayList.class);
```